# IE-11 Issue - Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module adComponents

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am facing an issue while running my AngularJS application in IE11.

When application runs in debugger mode, it does it properly. The issue comes only when I run it normally not in debug mode.

Also, I noticed that, if I run it without deploying it on server, it works perfectly fine. The issue comes only in **deploy mode** (To run it in deploy mode I made a grunt task that minifies the application and deploys it on server).

Here is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link href="styles/css/ncs_components.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="styles/css/adv_master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head> 

  <body>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="scripts/ext/require.js" data-main="scripts/main.js">    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: In IE, check in Developer Tools in which mode its working

Comment: Also if files are minified. controllers shld be something like this .controllers('ctrlname',['$scope',function($scope){}]

Comment: in IE , if i run application in deploy mode + debug mode is on, its working, the document mode is Edge.

Comment: It depends on how are you creatng your Angular controllers. As @RajkumarRathi said the files in Release mode are minified and thus angular doesn't know which dependencies to provide for your controller. You have to declare like this **app.controller("sampleCtrl", ["$scope", sampleCtrl]);** where sampleCtrl (second item in array) is the function that defines the controller.

Comment: In my application i have defined the controller same as above - app.controller('notesCtrl',['$scope'
            function($scope){
            
     }]) 
n m still getting the error.

Comment: The module adComponents is not a plugin , it is a custom plugin that we have created for our application. This module failed to load in deploy mode, but sometimes it loads  and sometimes not.